# How do I decompose a Predicate Expression into a query?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following class `Person`, with a custom `Where` method:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Where(Expression<Func<Person, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

How can I retrieve the `Expression` parameter names and values in an enumerable manner?

```
Person p = new Person();
p.Where(i => i.Name == "Shlomi" && i.Age == 26);
```

For the purpose of building a string query with parameters attached according to the name and value of the expression.

```
// Eventually I will convert the above into the following:
string Query = "select * from person where name = @Name AND Age = @Age";

SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[] { 
    new SqlParameter("@Name","Shlomi"),
    new SqlParameter("@Age","26")
};
```

Comment: What do you mean? can you provide expected input/output?

Comment: That makes very little sense... it is a fancy way of avoiding `p.Name == "Whatever" && p.Age = 28;`.  What's the point?  Selectors like that make sense on an enumerable object, not a single object.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like `p.Where("Name == \"Shlomi\" && Age == 26")` ?

Comment: I suspect the OP meant to ask "is it possible to deconstruct the expression tree used to create this lambda and produce an alternative representation of it?", i.e. he wants to be informed of how `IQueryable<T>` works behind the scenes.

Comment: If it is more information of the "behind-the-scenes" workings of `IQueryable<T>`, I find this to be a good start: [link](http://www.weirdlover.com/2010/05/11/iqueryable-can-kill-your-dog-steal-your-wife-kill-your-will-to-live-etc/)

Comment: I can get you some of the way there, and hopefully show you it isn't easy, with [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269822/linq-member-expression-getting-column-name/6270056#6270056).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I certainly think [you should follow StriplingWarrior's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520725/how-do-i-decompose-a-predicate-expression-into-a-query/7520824#7520824) and use LINQ to Entities or LINQ to SQL, but for the sake of reinventing the wheel (poorly) I'll build off of [a prior answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269822/linq-member-expression-getting-column-name/6270056#6270056).

```
// Start with a method that takes a predicate and retrieves the property names
static IEnumerable<string> GetColumnNames<T>(Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate)
{
    // Use Expression.Body to gather the necessary details
    var members = GetMemberExpressions(predicate.Body);
    if (!members.Any())
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            "Not reducible to a Member Access", 
            "predicate");
    }

    return members.Select(m => m.Member.Name);
}
```

Now you need to walk the expression tree, visiting each candidate expression, and determine if it includes a `MemberExpression`. The `GetMemberExpressions` method below will walk an expression tree and retrieve each of the `MemberExpression`s found within:

```
static IEnumerable<MemberExpression> GetMemberExpressions(Expression body)
{
    // A Queue preserves left to right reading order of expressions in the tree
    var candidates = new Queue<Expression>(new[] { body });
    while (candidates.Count > 0)
    {
        var expr = candidates.Dequeue();
        if (expr is MemberExpression)
        {
            yield return ((MemberExpression)expr);
        }
        else if (expr is UnaryExpression)
        {
            candidates.Enqueue(((UnaryExpression)expr).Operand);
        }
        else if (expr is BinaryExpression)
        {
            var binary = expr as BinaryExpression;
            candidates.Enqueue(binary.Left);
            candidates.Enqueue(binary.Right);
        }
        else if (expr is MethodCallExpression)
        {
            var method = expr as MethodCallExpression;
            foreach (var argument in method.Arguments)
            {
                candidates.Enqueue(argument);
            }
        }
        else if (expr is LambdaExpression)
        {
            candidates.Enqueue(((LambdaExpression)expr).Body);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the Expression is actually a tree.

For example, you have the following predicate:

```
Expression<Func<Person, bool>> expr = x => x.Name == "Shlomi" && x.Age == 26;
```

If you inspect expr, you'll see that it's body has "AndAlso" `NodeType` and it also has two properties for operands -- `Left` and `Right` each pointing to another `Expression` object with "Equal" `NodeType` which in turn again have two properties `Left` and `Right` which point to `Expression` of type `MemberAccess` and `Constant` respectively.

While you can process that tree and extract all information you need, you'll end up implementing your own LINQ2SQL provider, e.g. reinventing a wheel. If you feel so, I hope I provided enough information to start digging...

Comment: but how can i get name and value for "Left" for example ?

Comment: @ShlomiKomemi ok, let's say you have an expression like this `Expression<Func<Person, bool>> expr = x => x.Name == "AAA";` then `x.Name` part would be `((BinaryExpression)expr.Body).Left`. To get property name from it you can use `((MemberExpression)((BinaryExpression)expr.Body).Left).Member.Name`. But the problem is that you can't predict what the predicate expression tree will look like. So you need to traverse it, check each node's `NodeType` property, cast it to appropriate type and process it. `ExpressionType` enum contains 85 members so that's a lot of work...

Answer (score 1):

What you're wanting to do is very complicated, and there are entire frameworks that are built to do this, so you don't have to write the logic yourself. Take a look at LINQ to Entities and LINQ to SQL, e.g.

Comment: +1, sounds like he wants `db.People.Single(p => p.Name ==...`.