# How we can use Predicate<T> parameter

Tags: c#, predicate

How can I parse the contents `Predicate<T>` parameter in implementation of method? For example, I have this method:

```
public static List<MyEntity> Find(Predicate<MyEntity> filters)
```

When I use this method, I pass some predicate (i.e: `filters.Name == "xyz"`) to the method. I want to be able to determine the expression, i.e., to be able to generate SQL from it.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. What do you mean by "interpret" ?

Comment: If you want to be able to see, what is inside `filters` predicate, then you need to use expression tree type (`Expression<Predicate<MyEntity>>`) instead of compiled delegate type (`Predicate<MyEntity>`).

Comment: I want determine the caller of method pass filters.Name = "xyz" or pass filters.Type = 2 or ...

Comment: @PetSerAl ok may be Expression is better approch. Please give me you implementation. How can in use this parameter in body of method. For example  i want generate dynamic SQL base on predicate

Comment: @mmtemporary "For example i want generate dynamic SQL base on predicate" - it would have been good to open with that.
This might be somewhere to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520725/how-do-i-decompose-a-predicate-expression-into-a-query

Comment: Updated OP to better reflect what is being asked.

Comment: You cannot do that with a `Predicate` you will need an `Expression` as in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

As you may know, `Preidcate<T>` represents a method that takes a parameter of type `T` and returns a `bool` value. To use it, just treat it as a method.

Here is an example:

```
var entity = <get an entity some where>;
if (filters(entity)) {
    // entity satisfies the predicate
}
```

Judging from the name and signature of your method, you seem to want to find all the entities that satisfies a predicate. Maybe something like this:

```
var list = new List<Entity>();
foreach (var entity in <get all entities>) {
    if (filters(entity)) {
        list.Add(entity)
    }
}
return list;
```

> I want interpret it.

No you cannot interpret what's inside a predicate, which is a delegate. Delegates are black boxes. The caller of the delegate don't need to know what the delegate actually does. If you really want to know what it does, use expression trees, but I think `Predicate` should be used in this case.

Comment: OK but we can't load all data from database and apply this filters. suppose we want generate dynamic SQL base on predicate and execute that. if expression tree is better approach please write some code and replace with Predicate<T>

Comment: @mmtemporary Please see the documentation link I provided, especially the part at the bottom, "parsing expression trees"